# Restore package and its dependencies after messing it up

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, 22.04, openssl

Trying to fix a dependency problem I made a mess in my Ubuntu 22.04.
Now I cannot run `openssl` anymore:

```
$ openssl version
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It actually searches for that library:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/openssl 
/usr/bin/openssl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.0' not found (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd0cef6000)
    libssl.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x00007f78538b0000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007f785346e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7853246000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7853a53000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found
```

But it shouldn't because IIRC last version is based on SSL 3.x. In fact:

```
$ apt-cache depends openssl
openssl
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libssl3
  Suggests: ca-certificates
```

Furthermore `libssl1` is not available in `jammy`.
I tried with the usuals:

```
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt --reinstall install openssl
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssl
```

but nothing has changed.

What should I do in order to revert back the functionality of `openssl`?